# HTML5 Text with shadow effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on front-end development but couldn't implement the text with the shadow effect. Front-end is coded by HTML5, CSS3, bootstrap and AngularJS so in the design, there is the shadow effect at the text filed like the shadow effect in photoshop.

Please tell me how can I implement this shadow effect.

Comment: did you try any research? google `html5 text with shadow effect` gives a surprising number of useful results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** Internet Explorer 9 and earlier do not support the text-shadow property.

And should search Google before ask any  question. because in this my answer is in first result of  Google search.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #FF1111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Some Text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you search using the exact title in the question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX . yes dude. That's why am mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I realise, but the **exact** title of the question - shows OP made zero effort, but you still answered :p

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'text-shadow' property.

Read more about text shadow property: [Text Shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-shadow)

in this example it'll effects h1 elements.

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
}
```

**Syntax:**

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color;
```